# Why is this single-word address being resolved?

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns, localhost, hosts

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. On my work network, there's a single-word address (let's call it `foobar`) that is responding to pings and HTTP requests, *only from my machine*. The address is not a TLD, just a generic, project-related acronym.

Said address *shouldn't* be responding: There's no foobar entry in my `/etc/hosts` file. There's no reference to `foobar` in apache's `httpd.conf`, `sites-available` or `sites-enabled`, neither on my `resolv.conf` file, as follows:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search redacted.mycompany.com
```

Initially I thought it was redirecting to `localhost`, but if I open it on my browser it shows the nginx welcome page, and I'm running apache on my machine.

Sniffing `lo` and `eth0` shows the traffic is indeed coming from the network. Restarting the `resolvconf` service doesn't fix the issue. If I run:

```
service resolvconf stop
resolvconf --wipe-runtime-directories
service resolvconf start
```

then `foobar` stops resolving, but if I restart my machine it resolves again

Pinging `foobar` gets a reply from `foobar.redacted.mycompany.com`, a real address that works fine for other machines besides my own. Tracerouting or `mtr`'ing `foobar` shows a 5 hops until the destination, the same as tracerouting or mtr'ing `foobar.redacted.mycompany.com`.

Here's the output of the `dig foobar` command:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> foobar
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 52484
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;foobar.                IN  A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar  8 14:32:02 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 22
```

The issue happens both on Firefox (19.0) or Chrome (24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.12.04.1). Pressing <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd> doesn't change anything. **It doesn't happen on other two coworker's machines I've tested on the same subnetwork**.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Have you bought a coffee for your network admin recently or have you been totally neglecting him for a long time now?

Comment: Is `foobar` really the URL you are accessing?

Comment: @guntbert no, it's a single word that's not a TLD.

Comment: it could match a hostname of another system on the network, and thereby being resolved that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so you know, the entire client-side of the domain name system is entirely arbitrary; by convention programs are supposed to go through the system's C library to resolve hostnames, but technically they could entirely bypass that mechanism if they wanted to, either by shipping their own C library (statically compiled or otherwise), or using a completely custom DNS lookup system that does or does not use the DNS protocol.

Assuming a standard Ubuntu install, running programs that are linked to the system C library, you've got eglibc (which is a minor fork of GNU libc), and the default path of the file that tells gethostbyname() and other C library DNS resolution functions what DNS server to hit is /etc/resolv.conf.

`nameserver 127.0.0.1` means "use the DNS protocol to ask 127.0.0.1 about DNS queries" -- I assume you have a local caching DNS server that forwards to an upstream DNS server, such as `dnsmasq` or `bind`, for performance reasons (when doing a DNS query, it's a heck of a lot faster to query a server on your own computer than to go hit the network!)

`search redacted.mycompany.com` means "when trying to resolve foo, if it doesn't resolve directly then add the string .redacted.mycompany.com on the end and try again; if that works, return that result".

I think this is working "by design", but I don't know why it wouldn't work on coworkers' machines, unless they don't have the `search` line.

Comment: Turns out the two coworkers' machines I tested on had `foobar` on `/etc/hosts`, tested on a 3rd coworker's machine now and worked exactly as on my machine.